# Getting a class from one project to link with another class from another project

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a Windows Application where in MainWindow.xaml.cs I have a button click option to import, which goes off to run Main.Run, based on a spreadsheet that was dragged into a text box:

```
        private void Btn_Import_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Main.Run(Global.bindingObjects.spreadsheetTxtBxFile);

    }
```

The above code takes us to a Task, which should then go off to run DefunctRun in a different project, but it doesn't go to it when using a break point and F10 in debug:

```
        internal static void Run(string spreadsheetpath)
    {
        Task task = new Task(
             () =>
             {
                 try
                 {
                     PICSObjects.DefunctFields.DefunctRun(spreadsheetpath);


                 }
                 finally
                 {

                 }

             }
            );

        task.Start();
    }
```

The code that it should go off and perform, which I need to have the spreadsheet path turned into a dataset which this class should do if it can be accessed.:

```
using InfExcelExtension;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PICSObjects
{
public static partial class DefunctFields
{
    public static void DefunctRun(string spreadsheetpath)
    {
        //Sets up string values to be used later//
        DataSet origdata = new DataSet();
        DataSet newdata = new DataSet();
        string filespath = @"";

        string output = @".xlsx".ToString();
        string searchtext = "";
        string currentscript = "";
        string readscript = "";



        //Converts the above Path string (which should be a spreadsheet) into a dataset with 
datatables//
        origdata = ExcelToDataset.ToDataSet(spreadsheetpath);

        //Sets up two new tables in new dataset//
        newdata.Tables.Add("Scripts");
        newdata.Tables.Add("Tables");

        //Add columns to the new tables//
        newdata.Tables["Scripts"].Columns.Add("ToRemove");
        newdata.Tables["Scripts"].Columns.Add("ScriptName");
        newdata.Tables["Scripts"].Columns.Add("RelatedTable");

        newdata.Tables["Tables"].Columns.Add("TableName");
        newdata.Tables["Tables"].Columns.Add("ScriptName");


        //Sets the directory to browse in from the filespath specified at the top//
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filespath.ToString());

        //Goes through each file in specified directory that has .sql as the extension//
        foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.sql"))
        {
            currentscript = file.Name.ToString();
            readscript = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName).ToLower();

            //Goes through each "Field" value from the column and sets to Lower Case//
            foreach (DataRow dr in origdata.Tables["Fields"].Rows)
            {
                searchtext = dr["ToRemove"].ToString().ToLower();

                //If the Field value appears in the file it's currently looking at, it'll put it 
into our new dataset's new datatable//
                if (readscript.Contains(searchtext))
                {
                    DataRow row = newdata.Tables["Scripts"].NewRow();
                    row["ToRemove"] = searchtext;
                    row["ScriptName"] = currentscript;
                    row["RelatedTable"] = dr["Table"];

                    newdata.Tables["Scripts"].Rows.Add(row);

                }


            }

            //Whilst going through the files in the specified folder, we also look at what tables from origdata that are mentioned in the files as these are the defunct tables and need flagging//
            foreach (DataRow dr in origdata.Tables["Tables"].Rows)
            {
                searchtext = dr["Tables"].ToString();

                if (readscript.Contains(searchtext))
                {
                    DataRow row = newdata.Tables["Tables"].NewRow();
                    row["TableName"] = searchtext;
                    row["ScriptName"] = currentscript;


                    newdata.Tables["Tables"].Rows.Add(row);

                }


            }
        }

        newdata.ToWorkBook(output);

        Process.Start(output);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jay,

Where are you putting your break point? Because if your break point is in the Run method then doing an F11(Step Into) might not work because you are calling the DefunctRun method on another thread. If so try putting your break point on the DefunctRun method. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to like that either. I goes back to the MainWindow.xaml then just doesn't go anywhere else when trying to step through.

Comment: You've got no Catch block in the try so if it errors then nothing will happen and you'll have no idea what went wrong. Add a catch block, put a break in it and check whether there's any error.

Comment: Added a catch block in, but no errors triggered it into action

Comment: Your DefunctFields class seems to be defined as a partial, is that for a reason? I seems like you are using it as a service in which case no need to define it as a partial class.

Answer (score 0):

Ive sorted this one now. Just needed a fair bit of tweaking, based on everyone's comments